# Is there a Rails way to translate model names for usage in title (i.e. titleize?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I18n provided a convenient way to translate model names. Take the example from [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

```
I18n.backend.store_translations :en, inbox: {
  one: 'one message',
  other: '%{count} messages'
}
I18n.translate :inbox, count: 2
# => '2 messages'

I18n.translate :inbox, count: 1
# => 'one message'
```

This is good enough if I want to show "one message", "2 messages", and etc.

But what if I also want to show "Message" (for example, in the menu)? Do I have to create another totally different entry in the I18n files? Is there some Rails way to do this? like:

```
 I18n.backend.store_translations :en, inbox: {
      title: 'Message'
      zero: 'no messages'
      one: 'one message',
      other: '%{count} messages'
    }
```

Comment: I had a look at the source for `titleize` and I don't think it's possible; `titleize` doesn't appear to consult `I18n` before it does its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`titleize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) for making it look like a title, and [`pluralize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) for making it pluralize.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this, but I don't think titleize and pluralize are internationalization capable. They only work for English, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think Rails `mb_chars` will do this with unicode rules.

I was surprised to see you needed this, because I'm used to thinking of `mb_chars` in Rails as being a leftover from ruby 1.8 days which no longer has any use. But it looks like this is one place where default Rails titleize does not do the right i18n thing, but it will if you transform the string to an `mb_chars` proxy first.

```
irb(main):019:0> "\u01C9ab".titlecase   # "ǉab"
=> "ǉab"  # wrong

irb(main):021:0> "\u01C9ab".mb_chars.titlecase
=> Ǉab 
# right. Or at least closer and as close to right as Rails is gonna get, I'm not 
# sure if it should really be "ǈab", which is actually different. 
# I'm out of my league here.
```

I'm not really sure if the Rails devs would consider this a bug or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `pluralize` helper accepts the plural form as third parameter.

`pluralize 3, 'person', 'people'`

You can build a helper for your edge cases.